# Jensen's inequality proof explanation

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis, contest-math, proof-explanation, functional-inequalities

I was reading a proof of Jensen's inequality on convex functions, and I need some help understanding it. The proof is as follows:

$$f(t_1x_1+\dots+t_nx_n) = f((1-t_n)\left(\frac{t_1}{1-t_n}x_1+\dots+\frac{t_{n-1}}{1-t_n}x_{n-1}\right)+t_nx_n)$$
$$\le (1-t_n) f\left(\frac{t_1}{1-t_n}x_1+\dots+\frac{t_{n-1}}{1-t_n}x_{n-1}\right)+t_nf(x_n),(\text{convexity})$$
$$\le (1-t_n)\left[\frac{t_1}{1-t_n}f(x_1)+\dots+\frac{t_{n-1}}{1-t_n}f(x_{n-1})\right]+t_nf(x_n),(\text{induction})$$
$$=t_1f(x_1)+\dots+t_nf(x_n).$$

The proof is fairly simple but can someone please explain the inductive step for me? Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

The proof write-up you read isn't friendly to those new to induction, partly because it's easy to mistake the induction for circularity, partly because the base step is a little non-standard (we have to check two values of $n$, not just one). So let me spell out the argument a little more.

**Theorem**: for any $n\in\Bbb N$, a convex $f$ satisfies$$\sum_{i=1}^nt_i=1,\,t_i\ge0\implies f\left(\sum_{i=1}^n t_i x_i\right)\le\sum_{i=1}^nt_i f(x_i).$$

**Base step of inductive proof**: if $n=1$ then $t_1=1$, so the required result is $f(x_1)\le f(x_1)$, which is true; if $n=2$ the required result is$$t_1+t_2=1,\,t_i\ge0\implies f(t_1x_1+t_2x_2)\le t_1f(x_1)+t_2f(x_2),$$which is true by the convexity of $f$.

**Inductive step of inductive proof**: we prove if the result holds for $n=k\ge 2$ then it also holds for $n=k+1$. If $t_{n+1}=1$ other $t_i$ are $0$, so the required inequality is $f(x_{n+1})\le f(x_{n+1})$, which is true. If $t_{n+1}\ne1$,$$f\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}t_ix_i\right)=f\left((1-t_{k+1})\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{t_i}{1-t_{k+1}}x_i+t_{k+1}x_{k+1}\right).$$By convexity, we have the upper bound $$(1-t_{k+1})f\left(\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{t_i}{1-t_{k+1}}x_i\right)+t_{k+1}f(x_{k+1}).$$By the inductive hypothesis (i.e. the $n=k$ case of the result), we get an upper bound on the first term, so$$f\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}t_ix_i\right)\le(1-t_{k+1})\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{t_i}{1-t_{k+1}}f(x_i)+t_{k+1}f(x_{k+1})=\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}t_if(x_i).$$Our inductive step is now complete.

Answer (score 1):

The inductive assumption is that $$f(\lambda_1 x_1+\dots+\lambda_{n-1}x_{n-1})\leq \lambda_1 f(x_1)+\dots+\lambda_{n-1}f(x_{n-1})$$ already holds if $\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\lambda_j=1$ and since $\sum_{j=1}^{n}t_j=1$ one has

$\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\frac{t_j}{1-t_n}=\frac{1-t_n}{1-t_n}=1$.

Comment: But the assumption $f(\lambda_1 x_1+....+\lambda_{n-1}x_{n-1})\leq \lambda_1 f(x_1)+...+\lambda_{n-1}f(x_{n-1})$ is jensen's inequality which is what we want to prove.

Comment: Not sure if I understand Your question, its the inductive hypothesis for $n-1$, for $n=1$ You have $t_1=1$ and $f(x_1)\leq f(x_1)$ is trivial (equality holds), then the inductive step...

Comment: Thats the way induction works, You assume what You want to prove to hold for e.g. $n-1$ and then proof that it holds for $n$. Of course You need an anchor $n=1$

Comment: The reason it is had to discuss this problem is because $n$ is usually used in induction, however it happens to be the same variable used to describe the sequence $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$, so I would like to use the variable $m$ when talking about induction.

Comment: I think that induction in this case has to be done for $m+1$ rather than $m-1$. As the sequence goes $1,2,3,...,n$ and as our base case is $m=1$, $m+1$ is what works. However $m-1$, would work for a sequence of $1,0,-1, infinity$. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: The statement You prove by induction is that for $x_1,...,x_n\in \mathbb{R}$ and non-negative numbers $\lambda_1,..,\lambda_n$ that suffice $\sum_{j=1}^{n}\lambda_j=1$ and a convex function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ one has $f(\lambda_1 x_1+...+\lambda_n x_n)\leq \lambda_1 f(x_1)+...+\lambda_n f(x_n)$ and it depends on the integer $n$ and on no other integer and it is proven by induction over $n$ as described above

Comment: and You show this by showing it holds for $n=1$ and that if it holds for some $n-1$ it holds for its successor $n$, You might as well show if it holds for $n$ it holds for its successor $n+1$, these are just names and are really marginal.