# Maximum value of $\sin(A/2)+\sin(B/2)+\sin(C/2)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

So I came across a question in my textbook:

In triangle ABC, if $A$,$B$,$C$ represent angles, then find the maximum value of $\sin(A/2)+\sin(B/2)+\sin(C/2)$?

So I have already tried and best and put my blood,sweat and tears into this question..But I'm not able to go solve further!

So here's my approach:
By Using $\sin(C)+\sin(D)$ and $A+B+C= \pi$;

1. $2\sin(\frac{A+B}{4})\cos(\frac{A-B}{4})+\cos(\frac{A+B}{2})$
   Now,
   Using $\cos(2A)$ formula i.e, $1-2\sin^2(A)
   $
2. $2\sin(\frac{A+B}{4})\cos(\frac{A-B}{4})+1-2\sin^2(\frac{A+B}{4})$
3. So I got quadratic in variable $\sin(\frac{A+B}{4})$
4. $-2\sin^2(\frac{A+B}{4})+2\sin(\frac{A+B}{4})\cos(\frac{A-B}{4})+1$

But I dunno what to do After that

Can I solve this question using this method or I have to use a different approach!

BTW, the answer is **3/2**

Edit:I have just finished my high school and preparing for entrance exam IIT-JEE,So please don't use hard terms to solve this question.

**This solution is sent by my teacher, atleast make me understand this one**
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/51pCB.png]

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm) to format your posts.  To begin with, surround math expressions (including numbers) with `$` signs and use `_` for subscripts.  `$x_1$` comes out as $x_1$.

Comment: Since the maximum value of $\sin$ is $1$, it is impossible that the sum of three sines be any greater than $3$.

Comment: But the situation is in a triangle, so there are more restrictions. We can find a sharper bound.

Comment: I think this question is very similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/990418/maximum-value-of-sin-a-sin-b-sin-c

Comment: I updated my answer to give a differentiation-only option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you have stopped,
let $$z=-2\sin^2x+1+2\sin x\cos y$$

$$\iff2\sin^2x-2\sin x\cos y+z-1=0$$

As $\sin x$ is real, the discriminant must be $\ge0$

$\implies8(z-1)\le(-2\cos y)^2\le2^2$

$\implies8z\le4+8$

The equality occurs if $\cos^2y=1\iff\sin y=0$

and consequently $\sin x=\mp\dfrac{\cos y}2=\mp\dfrac12$

Comment: Sir from where 4or(2^2) came in discriminant ?

Comment: @Shuvam, What is the maximum value of $\cos^2y$

Comment: Sir it's 1 ..I mean it's 1

Comment: @Kumar,So, $$(-2\cos y)^2\le?$$

Comment: It maximum value i.e 4..yeah!

Comment: where did cos^2y term disappeared?In next step sir?

Comment: @Kumar, we find $$8(z-1)\le4$$

Comment: why so sir? And it seems like u have made an error in the answer then as u have assumed there 8(z-1)>_4

Comment: Please answer me sir!

Comment: @Shuvam, sorry for the typo

Answer (score 4):

Since $\sin x$ is [concave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function) on acute $x$, by [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) the maximum is found at $A/2=B/2=C/2=\pi/6$, as $3\sin\pi/6=3/2$.

Edit: since the OP mentioned in a comment on @B.Goddard's answer that they know differentiation, here's another proof the equilateral case achieves a maximum:

Keep using $\frac{C}{2}=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{A+B}{2}$. To extemize $\sin\frac{A}{2}+\sin\frac{B}{2}+\cos\frac{A+B}{2}$ simultaneously solve$$\tfrac12\cos\tfrac{A}{2}-\tfrac12\cos\tfrac{C}{2}=0,\,\tfrac12\cos\tfrac{B}{2}-\tfrac12\cos\tfrac{C}{2}=0$$viz. $A=B=C$. I'll leave the reader to check it's a maximum by considering second derivatives.

Comment: I dunno what is Jensen's inequality!

Comment: Essentially it is maximal when the triangle is equilateral.

Comment: @KumarShuvam I've added some links. For concave $f$, the mean of $f(x)$ is at most $f$ evaluated at the mean of $x$.(If you draw a diagram, you can probably see why this is quite intuitive; for a full proof of the [*convex*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function) case, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3214203).) In this case, we average over $A/2,\,B/2,\,C/2$.

Comment: So what's the flaw in my method??

Comment: Yes I think this solution goes above the OP's head for now. Nice application of Jensen 's though, kudos!

Comment: What if question asks for minimum value?

Comment: For this particular case, because sin(0) = sin(pi) = 0, the minimum value would be a degenerate triangle (ie, a line)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with Lagrange multipliers.  Maximize $f=\sin x/2 + \sin y/2+\sin z/2$  under the constraint $g=x+y+z = \pi$.

Then

$$\nabla f = \langle \cos(x/2)/2, \cos(y/2)/2, \cos(z/2)/2 
\rangle =\lambda\langle 1,1,1 \rangle = \nabla g.$$

This shows that $x=y=z$ and the maximal triangle is equilateral.

Comment: Lagrange multipliers is a Multivariable Calculus technique.  It's nice if you have the background, but if you don't understand it, don't worry, it's about 3 or 4 courses for you in the future.

Comment: I have just read precalculus..I just know how to do simple differnation and integration!

Answer (score 0):

In a triangle ABC, $A+B+C=\pi$
$$f(x)=\sin(x/2) \implies f''(x)=-\frac{1}{4}\sin(x/2)<0, x\in[0,2\pi].$$ So by Jemsen's inequality $$\frac{f(A/2)+f(B/2)+f(C/2)}{3} \le f(\frac{A+B+C}{6}).$$
$$\implies \frac{\sin (A/2)+\sin(B/2)+\sin{C/2}}{3} \le \sin\frac{\pi}{6}.$$
$$\implies \sin(A/2)+\sin(B/2)+\sin(C/2) \le \frac{3}{2}$$

Comment: We already tried that. Apparently, that method is too advanced.